# Beauty, chef and boxer

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Sarah, Megan, and Mike all attended a party last night. Sarah is a beauty pageant winner, Megan is a chef, and Mike is a boxer. The host of the party said that one person told a lie during the evening, one person told the truth, and one person did both. Using the clues below, can you determine who told a lie, who told the truth, and who did both?

Clues:

- Sarah said she cooked all the food for the party, but Megan claimed she made dessert.
- Mike said he knocked someone out recently in the ring, but Sarah said she saw him lose his last match.
- Megan said she won a baking competition, but Mike said he heard she came in second place.

Comment: Hi FunGuy, and welcome to Puzzling! When you present logic puzzles here, it's good to be somewhat precise with your wording. Here, it seems the claims are intended to be mutually exclusive to some extent, but the claims are _just_ vague enough to leave room for both statements being true (or both false) at the same time. For example, Mike can be truthful about hearing an untrue thing, and a recent knock-out can have happened even though it wasn't in the last match. Also "one person told a lie" feels very strange, when each person has made two statements. Shouldn't that be "two lies"?

Comment: That's the tricky thing about that puzzle!

Comment: That sounds more like dodgy puzzle design than "tricky" to me. (Unless you intended the correct answer to be something silly, along the lines of "no, I cannot determine anything of the sort"). Also, I notice you say "that puzzle" instead of "this puzzle". If a puzzle is not of your own making, you need to credit the original author when posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if there are any more options that work, but one possibility is:

> **Mike told lies** - Lied about Megan not winning and lost his boxing match.

We can infer from this that Megan and Sarah both told the truth in their statements with Mike so...

> Either Sarah or Megan could be the one who told a lie and the truth, or the one who only told the truth since the remaining statement involves them both, resulting in one telling the truth and one telling a lie.